# How to populate a text field with its default value or leave it empty, all according to a choice from a dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, textfield

The form contains a drop down list and a text field with a default value, if the user changes the drop down list choice, the text field must be empty.
What's the suitable function in JavaScript to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If I get what you want I would suggest using jquery example is here http://jsfiddle.net/WHWyS/

```
 $('#myId').change(function() {
         $("#myInput").val("");
});
```